# What is $\int e^{e^x+x}dx$

Tags: integration

I am a bit confused about $\int e^{e^x+x}dx$. If we made a $u$-sub of $e^x$ then the derivative is $e^x$ and so we have $\int e^udu$. But since the derivative of $e^x$ is itself, couldn't we also do $\int u^2e^udu$? I think I did a mistake here, but what is it?

My logic of saying that $\int e^{e^x+x}dx=\int u^2e^udu$ is to multiply the derivative of
$u$ to the integrand.

Comment: Write out the steps leading to $u^2e^u\ du$.  Where does the $u^2$ come from?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} e^{e^x} = e^{e^x} e^x = e^{e^x +x}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @RossMillikan I multiplied the derivative of $u$ to the integrand (which is $u$).

Comment: The substitution $u=e^x$ in your second sentence is the correct one. However, I can't follow your third sentence at all. Is the $u$ at that point still equal to $e^x$? (Edit - I am basically reiterating @RossMillikan's question.)

Comment: $$\int e^{e^x + x} \, dx = \int e^{u + \ln(u)} \, \frac{du}u$$Now simplify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is here: let $\color{blue}{u=e^x}$ so that $\mathop{du}=e^x \mathop{dx}$. Then
\begin{align}
\int e^{e^x+x}\mathop{dx} &= \int e^{\color{blue}{e^x}}\cdot \color{blue}{e^x}\mathop{dx}\\
&=\int e^{\color{blue}{u}}\color{blue}{u}\mathop{dx}\\
\end{align}

Where would go from here? You cannot integrate this, since your differential is in terms of $x$, but you have your inegrand in terms of $u$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be much more clear to write our all of your variables and differentials in terms of the new substitution variable.

Recall that for some substitution $u=f(x)$, we can see that
$$\frac{du}{dx}=f'(x)\Longleftrightarrow \frac{dx}{du}=\frac{1}{f'(x)}\Longleftrightarrow dx=\frac{du}{f'(x)}$$

Hence, for your case, we have $u=e^x$, making $dx=\frac{du}{e^x}$. We can approach this two ways. First, we can attempt to cancel anything while remaining in our old variable and then substitute, or we can replace our integrand completely with the new variable.

Method 1 gives $$\int e^{e^x+x}dx = \int e^{e^x}\cdot {\color{red}{e^x}}\cdot \frac{du}{{\color{red}{e^x}}} = \int e^{e^x} du = \int e^u du$$
which is trivial.

The second method has us first noting that $x=\ln(u)$, so we have
$$\int e^{e^x+x}dx = \int e^{e^{\ln(u)}+\ln(u)}\cdot \frac{du}{u} = \int e^{e^{\ln(u)}}e^{\ln(u)}\cdot \frac{du}{u}= \int e^{u}\cdot {\color{red}{u}}\cdot \frac{du}{{\color{red}{u}}}$$
which also is trivial.

Hopefully this helped or at least made some sense?